# Ubuntu 12.04 login screen freezes / monitor problems

Tags: 12.04, login, freeze, monitor, fglrx

Just bought a new computer and installed Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit version.

After I enter my password, the screen freezes either at the login screen or with the ubuntu 12.04 LTS logo at the bottom. I rebooted with the reset button on my computer and it froze at a purple screen before even going to the login screen.

I think this is some problem with the graphics, but not 100% certain. When I assembled the computer at my friends house and used his monitor, everything worked just fine. The issue happened when I brought the computer home and used my Acer monitor. The computer has a DVI port and I use a DVI->VGA converter with a VGA cable.

When the login screen does appear, it starts from the middle of the screen and wraps around from the left. I did Ctrl+Alt+F1 and entered the terminal mode. I was able to successfully login from the terminal. So nothing is wrong with my files, maybe something with Unity. I did a "grep Failed /var/log/xorg.0.log" and it gave me a "Failed to load module "fglrx".

I tried to do `sudo apt-get install fglrx` but that didn't work because it couldn't find any files named fglrx. I did a `locate fglrx` and it did find some fglrx-desktop files.

Any thoughts? I maybe missing drivers needed for the Acer monitor, but I don't know how to install drivers in Ubuntu. I have:

```
Acer S232HL LCD monitor
Asus Radeon HD 6670 graphics card
Intel Core i7 processor
```

**Edit:**
I found out that I don't have any fglrx installed on my system, except for

```
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/fglrx-driver.desktop
/usr/share/apport/package-hooks/source_fglrx-installer.py
/usr/share/jockey/handlers/fglrx.py
```

It seems that several attempts are being made to load some driver:

```
$ grep "autoconfigured driver" /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[ 9.937] (==) Matched fglrx as autoconfigured driver 0
[ 9.937] (==) Matched ati as autoconfigured driver 1
[ 9.937] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
[ 9.937] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
```

But the only available drivers are the following:

```
$ grep drivers /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[ 15.459] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/ati_drv.so
[ 15.466] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/radeon_drv.so
[ 15.481] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[ 15.482] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[ 15.492] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/ati_drv.so
[ 15.492] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[ 15.492] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[ 15.494] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/radeon_drv.so
```

Also, I found [this great troubleshooting guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/VideoDriverDetection?action=show&redirect=X/Troubleshooting/FglrxInteferesWithRadeonDriver) and followed their instructions in "Problem: Video card not supported by driver"

```
$ lspci -nn | grep VGA
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Turks [Radeon HD 6670] [1002:6758]
```

But running `grep -i 10026758 /usr/share/xserver-xorg/pci/*.ids` gave me nothing.

I do have a file named `/usr/share/xserver-xorg/pci/geode.ids`, but it has no PCI ID 1002:6758.

Also, I don't have any file named `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. I don't understand where exactly the problem is. It maybe that the X server can't find `1002:6758` in `geode.ids` and defaults to vesa. Is there a way to obtain the correct `.id`s file? Or should I download new AMD Catalyst Display Drivers (fglrx) from the AMD website?

Answer (score 2):

The following Instructions below explain how install the latest ATI Catalyst Video driver on a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 Precise. Please follow these commands...

## Step 1

Download Latest driver from [here](http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-driver-installer-12-4-x86.x86_64.run).

Create a folder name **Catalyst** in desktop and put the downloaded file in there.

## Step 2

Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 xserver-xorg-core
dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo reboot
```

After reboot, open a terminal and type:

```
cd ~/Desktop
cd Catalyst
sudo sh amd-driver-installer-*.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/precise
```

This will creat 3 **.deb** package in that following directory. Then, type:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.*deb
```

This will install this package in your machine. If any error occurred type `sudo apt-get -f install`. It will fix dependency problem. Then again install these package by typing `sudo dpkg -i *.*deb`.

If you don't get error in second time then you are good to go. Type:

```
sudo amdconfig --initial -f
sudo reboot
```

After reboot check with:

```
fglrxinfo
```

You will see like this:

```
display: :0.0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Mobility Radeon HD 6000 Series 
OpenGL version string: 3.3.11631 Compatibility Profile Context
```

Answer (score 1):

When you can't find a package you believe exists, the first thing to do is [search for it here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/).

[These search results](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=fglrx&searchon=names&suite=precise&section=all) reveal [the package exists](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/fglrx) and is provided in the **restricted** [component](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu).

First, run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This updates your Ubuntu system's local database of what packages and versions are available for installation and where they can be obtained.

Then try this again:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

(You should always run `sudo apt-get update` before running `sudo apt-get install ...`, unless you have run `sudo apt-get update` very recently.)

If that doesn't work, open the Software Sources window. (One way to do this is to open the Update Manager and click the **Settings...** button at the lower-left corner of the window.)

[image: Software Sources window, showing the Ubuntu Software tab]

In the **Ubuntu Software** tab, under **Downloadable from the Internet**, make sure **Proprietary drivers for devices (restricted)** is checked. Then click **Close**.

Then, in the Terminal, try installing `fglrx` again:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

By the way, you should also be able to install this and any other proprietary drivers in **Additional Drivers**, though occasionally there is a driver that will work on your system, and is provided by official Software Sources in Ubuntu, but isn't listed there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It turned out that I had to do a lot of upgrades since I had bought a new computer. I did "sudo apt-get update", "sudo apt-get upgrade", and "sudo apt-get install fglrx". I was finally able to login and get to the Ubuntu Desktop without having to do Ctrl+Alt+F1.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is with your Radeon card.  fglrx is in the repositories and if you aren't able to install it then you may not have any network connectivity.